# Linking a program with two static libraries each containing functions that depend on functions in the other?

Tags: c, static-libraries

I'm actually trying to call a function `a` (stocked in liba.a) from another function `b` (stocked in libb.a) but I have a linkage error.

There are my files:

a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void a()
{
  printf("a\n");
}
```

b.c

```
void a();
void b()
{
  a();
}
```

main.c

```
void b();
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  b();
  return (0);
}
```

And how I compiled

```
gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.c
ar rc liba.a a.o
ar rc libb.a b.o
ranlib liba.a
ranlib libb.a
gcc main.c liba.a libb.a
```

(the exact message error)

```
b.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `a'
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?
Thanks for your time

EDIT:
It appears that library order in the command line matters.
But in my real problem libA depends on libB and libB depends on libA (which the MCVE code doesn't demonstrate).

Comment: Does anything change if you swap the order? `gcc main.c libb.a liba.a`

Comment: The order of the libraries on the command line is important. If library B depends on library A, then B must come before A on the command line.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/lib/libsearch.html

Comment: "A function from another function"? You cannot call a function from anywhere else in C. `main` is also a function. What is your **specific** problem? And what did you try to solve it yourself and how/why did it fail?

Comment: On an unrelated note, unlike C++ declaring a function without any explicit arguments (like you declare `a` and `b`) doesn't mean that the function takes no argument. If a function takes no argument you must specify `void` as the argument (as in `void a(void);`). Of you have only an empty set of parentheses like you do in the code you show, in C it means that the function takes an indeterminate number of arguments of indeterminate type. The exact arguments are determined when you first call the function (which might lead to problems if you have different calls in different translation units).

Comment: Actually library A depends on B and library B depends on A
(for differents functions)

Comment: Mutual dependencies between a pair of static libraries is a special form of purgatory. If you can't change things so that only one library calls functions in the other (the simplest solution), then your best bet is probably to combine the two libraries into one for neither is a standalone unit any more. You could switch to shared libraries which would hide the problem. Other options include rescanning the pair of static libraries multiple times (is twice each enough?), and creating symbols that are used to ensure that the right stuff is loaded (which is hard and unreliable and to be avoided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: It appears that library order in the command line matters. But in my real problem libA depends on libB and libB depends on libA (which the MCVE code doesn't demonstrate).

Your real problem, then, is you've painted yourself in a corner.  The right thing to do is arrange the two libraries so that one is entirely independent of the other, and put that one after the other in the link command.

Without making that change, you might get away with mentioning the first library twice,

```
gcc main.c liba.a libb.a liba.a
```

The linker is pretty simple-minded when it comes to name resolution.  Starting with a list of unresolved names, it marches through the list of libraries, resolving names as it finds them.  It won't notice that you give it liba.a twice; it will resolve the `a` names supplied by `b`, and then the `b` names supplied by `a`.

But that trick is likely to bite you one day (if it works at all).  Best, as I said, is to sort out your dependencies and simplify things for yourself and those who follow you.

Answer (score -1):

Create the following `Makefile` in the same directory that you already have `a.c`, `b.c` and `main.c`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make

ar:
        gcc -o a.o -c a.c
        gcc -o b.o -c b.c
        gcc -o m.o -c main.c
        ar rc liba.a a.o
        ar rc libb.a b.o
        ar rc libm.a m.o
        ranlib liba.a
        ranlib libb.a
        ranlib libm.a
        gcc -o main m.o a.o b.o

install:
        gcc -o a.o -c a.c
        gcc -o b.o -c b.c
        gcc -o m.o -c main.c
        gcc -o main m.o a.o b.o

clean:
        rm -f *.o
        rm -f *.a
        rm -f main
```

Basically, your question is an example of multiple files development in C.

- If you issue the `make install` command, the `Makefile` will compile your program using standard gcc compilation process.
- If you issue the `make ar`, the compilation will be `ar` packaging compliance.
- If you issue the `make clean`, the `Makefile` will clean your previous build

Comment: If you are going to link the a.o and b.o objects along with main, what would be the point of making the libraries in the first place?

Comment: In `gcc -c a.c`, without using the gcc's object switch, the gcc automatically will create a.o object for you. In case of my answer, I'm passing the object name to gcc using `gcc -o a.o -c a.c`. Basically, both of these commands will produce the same output.